# How to set event on stage while mouse dragging?

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I want to fire an event while dragging stage. I found a lot of examples about undecorated stage dragging which has set event (MouseEvent) on pane but not on stage. Is there any way through which I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work just to observe the x and y properties of the stage?

i.e.:

```
final Stage stage ;
// ...

ChangeListener<Number> stageMoveListener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number new Value) {
        System.out.println("Stage moved to "+stage.getX()+", "+stage.getY());
    }
});
stage.xProperty().addListener(stageMoveListener);
stage.yProperty().addListener(stageMoveListener);
```